# Apache as a reverse proxy not working for gunicorn

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, reverse-proxy, django, gunicorn

My Goal is to let client connect through `https` connection but apache serve it to my application which is running on same server over `http`. Here is my minimalistic apache configuration file (for incoming http requests i am simply redirecting all request to https):

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80

LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@abc.com
  ServerName abc.com
  ServerAlias www.abc.com
  RequestReadTimeout header=90 body=90

  DocumentRoot /path/to/my/project
  LogLevel warn
  WSGIDaemonProcess abc_ssl processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=10
  WSGIProcessGroup abc_ssl
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project.wsgi
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /home/django/.ssh/abc.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/django/.ssh/server.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /home/django/.ssh/abc.ca-bundle

  RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-SSL "on"
  RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED_PROTO "https"
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  <Location /stream/>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from All
  </Location>

  ProxyPass /stream/ http://127.0.0.1:8001/
  ProxyPassReverse /stream/ http://127.0.0.1:8001/

</VirtualHost>
```

Clearly the gunicorn is running and listening on `http://127.0.0.1:8001/`:

```
2013-08-31 05:05:51 [15025] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.2
2013-08-31 05:05:51 [15025] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8001 (15025)
2013-08-31 05:05:51 [15025] [INFO] Using worker: eventlet
2013-08-31 05:05:51 [15044] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15044
2013-08-31 05:05:51 [15045] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15045
2013-08-31 05:05:51 [15046] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15046
```

But on browser i can only see `NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://abc.com/stream/`. Please help me i am stuck, really appreciate that.

Comment: Are you trying to use mod_wsgi, or proxy to the running gunicorn instance?  With both mod_wsgi and mod_proxy set to handle the request, I'm not sure which one "wins".  Check the gunicorn access log to determine whether the request is making it there or if mod_wsgi is preventing the proxy configuration from functioning.

Comment: Enable access log and error log in gunicorn, see if your requests to /stream really hit the gunicorn first.

Answer (score 0):

Oopss! it was a silly mistake. The `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` should be:

```
ProxyPass /stream/ http://127.0.0.1:8001/stream/ #<-- was missing /stream/ here
ProxyPassReverse /stream/ http://127.0.0.1:8001/stream/
```